# Parallelly running Embedded Kafka spring boot tests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka, junit5, spring-kafka-test

I have some spring boot tests that are using Kafka internally. For Kafka functionality, I am using `@EmbeddedKafka` annotation on each of the test classes that are using Kafka (with same server on each test, localhost:9092).

```
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, brokerProperties = { "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092", "port=9092" })
class SampleIntegrationTest extends Base integration test {
   // code
}
```

The tests are passing when I run individually or sequentially in test suite but **failing when I run the test suite parallelly**. In `junit-platform.properties` setting:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = same_thread
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default = concurrent
```

Getting **resource access exception** on some of the tests. Is there someway these tests can be run parallelly with `@EmbeddedKafka`?

Also just to mention, **some of these Kafka related integration tests** internally sends data on **same topics**.

Thanks.

Comment: See if this one helps you somehow: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#same-broker-multiple-tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by creating an **EmbeddedKafkaBroker** Bean (creating it conditionally using seperate property file that I use for IntegrationTests). That always starts kafka server at a fixed port and it is can be used by  all integration tests, even while running in parallel.

```
      @Bean
      public EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker() {
        EmbeddedKafkaBroker kafkaEmbedded = new EmbeddedKafkaBroker(COUNT, false, PARTITIONS);
        kafkaEmbedded.brokerProperties(Map.of(
          LISTENERS, LISTENERS_URL,
          PORT, PORT_NUMBER,
          LOG_DIRECTORY, EMBED_KAFKA_LOGS
        ));
        return kafkaEmbedded;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

When running your tests in parallel, you are encountering resource access exceptions because multiple tests are trying to use the same Kafka broker port (9092) and the same topics. To avoid these conflicts, you can create a unique Kafka broker and topics for each test.

To achieve this, you can use dynamic ports and unique topics for each test.

Update the `@EmbeddedKafka` annotation to use a dynamic port:

```
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, brokerProperties = { "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:0" })
```

Inject the `EmbeddedKafkaBroker` instance into your test class and configure your Kafka producer and consumer with the dynamically assigned port:

```
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, brokerProperties = { "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:0" })
class SampleIntegrationTest extends BaseIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        Map<String, Object> producerProps = KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(embeddedKafkaBroker);
        // configure your Kafka producer using producerProps

        Map<String, Object> consumerProps = KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps("testGroup", "true", embeddedKafkaBroker);
        // configure your Kafka consumer using consumerProps
    }

    // code
}
```

Use unique topics for each test. Instead of using hardcoded topic names, you can generate unique topic names for each test:

```
class SampleIntegrationTest extends BaseIntegrationTest {

    private String uniqueTopic;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        uniqueTopic = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        // ...
    }

    // code
}
```

Comment: Using different ports and topics for each test might not be possible since the kafka service logic within is pushing messages to a pre-defined Kafka host and with pre-defined topics. Is there some other way round to this? With or without @EmbeddedKafka?

Answer (score 0):

### Problem 1 - kafka brokers on different ports

You will likely want to use dynamic ports when running a test suite so each test class uses a different kafka broker. You'll want each broker on its own set of ports.

When using dynamic ports you want the following:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyApplication.class}, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "property.for.kafka.host=${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}",
        "property.for.zookeeper.host=${spring.embedded.zookeeper.connect}",
})
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, ports = 0, zookeeperPort = 0,
               topics = {"my-topic"},
               brokerProperties = {"auto.create.topics.enable=true"})
class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka;

}
```

The `@EmbeddedKafka` annotation supports the ability to set specific ports or it will use dynamic random ports if the value is set to zero.

If you need these ports to set the properties that your application uses when creating the producer/consumer you can assign your projects properties with the random ports via `spring.embedded.kafka.brokers` and `spring.embedded.zookeeper.connect`.

With the above config, calling

`embeddedKafkaBroker.getBrokerAsString` will return 127.0.0.1:33775

The other properties are as follows:

```
spring.embedded.kafka.brokers=127.0.0.1:33775
spring.embedded.zookeeper.connect=127.0.0.1:44017
property.for.kafka.host=127.0.0.1:33775
property.for.zookeeper.host=127.0.0.1:44017
```

### Problem 2 - consumers

Lets say we have two test classes being run within the same suite that are both utilising a unique kafka broker. You will need to be careful that the consumer created within the Spring application context (i.e. your production consumer) has a unique consumer group for each test.

The consumer from the first test connects to a topic created in the embedded kafka of the first test. It will connect with a given consumer-group.

Possibly the consumer from the first test, continues to poll even after the first test's embedded kafka is torn down. So when the second test starts, the consumer from the first test is still hanging around and starts reading messages from the second test's broker. If the consumers in test 1 and test 2 both share a consumer group, you may find the consumer from test 2 is not getting the messages as expected because the consumer from test 1 is stealing them.

I have struggled to confirm this but suspect the cause of test failures in pipelines is a result of the above.